# Do browsers change URLs of saved bookmarks in response to 301 redirection?

Tags: browser, bookmarks, url, redirection

HTTP status code 301 is used to indicate that content has moved permanently, and that the returned URL should be used to access the requested content in future.

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-62) says

> Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link references to the request-URI to one or more of the new references returned by the server, where possible.

Do any browsers actually implement this and change a bookmark's URL?

Comment: The "client with link editing capabilities" mentioned in the RFC may refer to a program that is both [a web browser and a web page editor](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/ "Amaya"). That is, if you are viewing a page you have edit rights for and you open a link with an old URL that returns a 301 response, the browser-editor should update the link to use the new URL from the 301 response. (Although Amaya doesn't seem to use 301 responses to update links when I played around with it.) In other words, the RFC may not be talking about bookmarks at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tested the web browsers on my computer and none of them changed the address stored in the bookmark.

- Internet Explorer 7 - **no**
- Firefox 3.0 - **no**
- Chrome 4.0 - **no**
- Opera 10.01 - **no**

---

#### How I tested

First, I found some addresses that return a 301. For example, google.com returns a 301 to www.google.com

In each browser, I went to the bookmark editor, and manually created a bookmark for the old address. I visited the bookmark, then looked at the bookmark's properties to see if the address was updated to the new address.

---

While working on this, I came across a similar Stack Overflow question you may find interesting: [Client Web Browser Behavior When Handling 301 Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666089).

Comment: Many thanks for that, and for finding the related SO question.

Comment: Bavi_H, your test result is different here than in the similar question you refer, (where you actually state "yes" to Chrome and Opera). Could you please update your answers?

Comment: @Jesper Rønn-Jensen: The questions are asking about different things (if a bookmark address is changed; if the connection to the old server is skipped).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so. They could at least ask you couldn't they?

"Such and such a site has updated their url. Would you like to update your bookmark?"

Answer (score 1):

Chromium doesn't, but there was an issue raised for this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70377, which was closed due to inactivity and lack of feedback.