# Do common browsers update bookmarks when they receive 301?

Tags: browser, bookmarks

> 301 redirects are permanent. They mean that the page has moved, and
>   they request any search engine or user agent coming to the page to
>   update the URL in their database. This is the most common type of
>   redirect that people should use.

I migreated a certain part of my application from `baseurl/app` to `app.mydomain.com`. Eventually, 
I would like to shut down `baseurl/app`. Hence, I was wondering if people who bookmarked `mydomain.com/app` will have their browser bookmark automatically updated.

Comment: No they don't. The user must update it themselves.

Answer (score 6):

I can say that most major browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera) don't update their bookmarks themselves, so it might break bookmarks for some users when you stop the 301 redirect. You could check the server access log for these URL's to see if they are still commonly used. And inform users using the old URL's before shut down.

See also similar questions:

- [Do browsers change URLs of saved bookmarks in response to 301 redirection?](https://superuser.com/questions/151366/do-browsers-change-urls-of-saved-bookmarks-in-response-to-301-redirection)
- [Client Web Browser Behavior When Handling 301 Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666089/client-web-browser-behavior-when-handling-301-redirect)